# on click post thumb nail redirect to another site

Tags: php, wordpress

This  is the code

```
<a href="`<?php the_content(); ?>`" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); }?></a>
```

On Clicking The Post Thumbnail I want to redirect to another site
I have given link in content as well as in link of the content I cannot figure it out
So, Can anyone help?? Thank You!!

Comment: Are you aware of HTML and what it does?

Comment: You're looking for the 'header' php function (probably) but you clearly have no idea of what you're doing ;) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: What does he wants to do? I dont understand him

Comment: @Xatenev: not sure he wants to redirect through PHP (for some reason) or through a simple anchor.. From what we can see he clearly has no idea of what he has to do, and we don't understand what he has to do either, lol

Comment: What is the_content() and what is the_title() :O?

Comment: Why are you defining functions for setting the path and title?

Comment: i used the content url in th href so on click i may get redirect to the link which i provided

Comment: He just wants to formulate a regular html link. the_content() is a wordpress funtion, it wont do what he wants

Comment: Ah this href is wordpress specific, k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<a href="<?php echo the_content(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title();?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); }?>
</a>
```